# MariaDB JDBC chokes on column name containing curly brackets

Tags: java, jdbc, mariadb

I have a very simple SQL query I need to run

```
SELECT `id`, `{Document id}` FROM `test`.`test` LIMIT 10;
```

where `{Document id}` is a column name. Whenever I run it through MariaDB JDBC, it fails with error `unknown escape sequence`. From my understanding `{CALL ...}` is used to call stored procedure with a JDBC `CallableStatement`.

How do I escape it? I want JDBC to treat it as literal string without special meaning. `\` didn't work for me.

As mentioned in deleted answer by @a_horse_with_no_name, there is [setEscapeProcessing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#setEscapeProcessing(boolean)). But it's not supported by a lot of connectors (example [MariaDB](https://github.com/MariaDB/mariadb-connector-j/blob/master/src/main/java/org/mariadb/jdbc/MariaDbStatement.java#L804)).

Comment: Which JDBC driver are you using? I guess MySQL Connector/J, or are you really using the deprecated JdbcOdbc bridge? It seems a limitation (bug?) of that driver that it doesn't ignore something that looks like an escape within a quoted column name.

Comment: So you are using the MariaDB connector, and not ODBC?

Comment: As per mariaDB documentaion `PreparedStatement` are always escaped, so try `PreparedStatement` if you are using `Statement`.

Comment: Instead of \`{Document Id}\` one might try "{Document Id}" as double quotes are the _standard_ SQL name escapes, backtick is MySQL specific.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your issue with mysql-connector-java-5.1.44. `ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT \`{Document id}\` FROM test.test");` works fine for me.

Comment: @Joop the project I am working on, use Maria's connector for some reason

Comment: @Gord ^^^^^^^^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have confirmed this issue using mariadb-java-client-2.2.5. It is not an issue with mysql-connector-java-5.1.44 so you might want to [report this issue to MariaDB](https://jira.mariadb.org/projects/CONJ/issues/).

Following the suggestion by @JoopEggen in the comments above, I got it to work with MariaDB JDBC by adding `sessionVariables=sql_mode=ANSI_QUOTES` to the connection string and using

```java
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT \"{Document id}\" FROM test.test");
```